# McDonald's or KFC in eastern same as west?

Tags: food-and-drink

I hope my question is related to travel. I want to know whether the ingredients and taste for burgers in these chain restaurants are same in both east and west? Specifically Taiwan...

Comment: No, they are tailored to the local markets

Comment: It's not even the same in the US and UK

Answer (score 6):

No, they are tailored to the markets, taste preferences, religions and cultural sensitivities.

For example, in the US all the burgers are beef and the sandwiches are chicken or fish. There are no rice bowls. https://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en-us/full-menu.html

In india there is certainly no beef. The only meat option is chicken and the rest is vegetarian. There are plenty of rice bowls. https://www.mcdonaldsindia.com/products.html

Comment: No pork in turkey…

Comment: But some people told me that the taste is around same in all around the world. yes maybe beef type is different but they have similar taste. I dont know

Comment: Reminds me of when I (from the UK) had one in the US a fair few years ago. Definitely had a different taste, and much larger portions.

Comment: There are obvious differences and additions to the menu but how consistent is the taste and composition for items that are available in most places? Say fries or the Big Mac (outside of India)? Or the spices in KFC products?

Comment: "burgers are beef and sandwiches are chicken", aren't american burgers almost always sandwiches, or are you referring to people eating the patty without any bread?

Comment: @gerrit: they are two different categories on the US McDonalds menu. "A beef patty on a round bun" is a category on it's own here.